# Async search request using DirectoryNotificationControl won't retrieve deleted objects

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm using this search :

```
        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("CN=Users,DC=xx,DC=xxx", "(objectclass=*)",  SearchScope.OneLevel, new string[] {"isDeleted", "objectGUID", "uSNChanged"});
        request.Controls.Add(new DirectoryNotificationControl());        

        IAsyncResult result = Connection.BeginSendRequest(
            request,
            PartialResultProcessing.ReturnPartialResultsAndNotifyCallback, 
            RunAsyncSearch, // Callback that processes responses
            null
            );
```

and it won't notify when user has been deleted. I also tried to add

```
request.Controls.Add(new ShowDeletedControl());
```

but it didn't help. I checked for tombstoneLifeTime (which is set to 180) in

```
CN=Directory Service,CN=Windows NT,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=xxx,DC=xxx
```

Weird thing is, that search from [this tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258310) returned only one result :

```
ldap_search_ext_s(ld, "<WKGUID=18E2EA80684F11D2B9AA00C04F79F805,DC=xxx,DC=xxx>", 2, "(objectclass=*)"), attrList,  0, svrCtrls, ClntCtrls, 6000, 10000 ,&msg) Getting 1 entries: Dn: CN=Deleted Objects,DC=xxx,DC=xxx
```

(18E2EA80684F11D2B9AA00C04F79F805 is a well known AD object GUID for CN=Deleted Objects)

Comment: Hi, Its been ages but do you have that example code. I dont get any response from my testing on mine and shy of seeing your post back process I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided LdapConnection from the example above with credentials of a user, **that is a member of Administrators group** on the server, where the desired Domain Controller is installed, but that was not enough. The code **must be run under elevated rights**, so running Visual Studio or the code "as administrator" fixed my isue. I also was able to view deleted objects via running ldp.exe with elevated rights.